# Wordpress custom field parameter use

Tags: php, wordpress

Want to use the parameter that I get over the Custom Field Option in Wordpress for an included site with searching results.

This is my code (without the parameter everything runs, but how can I use the parameter in the URL?):

```
<?php $parameter = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'searchingword', false); ?>
        <?php foreach($parameter as $parameter) {
            echo file_get_contents_curl('http://www.domain.com/searching.php?search=.$parameter.');         } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Try this:

```
echo file_get_contents_curl('http://www.domain.com/searching.php?search='. $parameter);
```

And in the foreach loop you have to use 2 different variables:

```
foreach($parameter as $param) {
    echo file_get_contents_curl('http://www.domain.com/searching.php?search='. $param);
    ...
```

Comment: Great that is it. Thanks